# F#: Using Enumerable.GroupBy in F#

Tags: .net, f#

I am new to F# and I am currently very unfamiliar with .NET APIs.

I want to use the [.NET Enumerable.GroupBy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx) in an F# program. Here is the relevant sample from my code:

```
let atLeast2Values (key , values) =
    Seq.length values > 1

let findGroupsOfTwoOrMore (directory: string) =
    let getPath = snd
    let getLength = fst

    let fileNameLengthPairs = new DirectoryInfo(directory)
                              |> getFileLengthAndFileNameTuples

    fileNameLengthPairs.GroupBy(keySelector = getLength, elementSelector = getPath)
    |> Seq.filter atLeast2Values
```

Unfortunately, running this code returns the following error message:

> Program.fs(37,51): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
>   `Func<(int64 * string),'a>`
>   but here has type
>       `'b * 'c -> 'b`

How may I resolve this error?

EDIT: Here is the getFileLengthAndFileNameTuples function:

```
let rec getFileLengthAndFileNameTuples (dirInfo: DirectoryInfo) =
        seq {
            let nameLengthPairs = dirInfo.GetFiles()
                                  |> Seq.map (fun fileInfo -> (fileInfo.Length, fileInfo.FullName))

            yield! nameLengthPairs

            let subFolders = dirInfo.GetDirectories()

            for subFolder in subFolders do
                yield! getFileLengthAndFileNameTuples subFolder
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of `fileNameLengthPairs`? can you add `getFileLengthAndFileNameTuples`function ? You'd better use groupby provided by sequence (Seq.groupBy https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370445.aspx)

Comment: Hello Thomas. I have added the function as requested. I use Enumerable.GroupBy because I want to specify the element selector. Seq.groupBy in F# does not accomplish the same. Thanks.

Comment: `GroupBy(keySelector = Func<_, _>(getLength), elementSelector = Func<_, _>(getPath))` interestingly it seems to get the correct `Func` when you don't use named arguments: `GroupBy(getLength, getPath)`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `fileNameLengthPairs` is of type :

`val fileNameLengthPairs : seq<int * string>`

You can use the code below.

```
fileNameLengthPairs
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (length, _) -> length)
|> Seq.filter (fun (key, value) -> (Seq.length value) > 1)
```

It's better to use `Seq.groupBy` from F# module because this can be partially applied and code looks more fluent and functional.

Comment: `groupBy` is good.  If you need better performance you might need to resort to the linq `toLookup` though.